# Como hacer una llamada a un API desde c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un pequeño código en c# donde tratando de consultar un API, este api esta con un token, he buscado en Internet e intento mandarlo de las diferentes maneras pero al final siempre me sale el mismo error

> response status code does not indicate success 401 (unauthorized)

Este api lo hice yo, lo pruebo desde insomnia, desde el frontend y todo funciona exactamente igual, pero ahora aquí en c# no se de que manera hacerlo funcionar.

```
 DateTime predate = dtpPrepoliza.Value;
 string preformating = predate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 string token = "mitokem";
 //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
 var url = "https://apy.xxxxx.com/v2/prepo?cfecha=2021-08-05";
 //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $ "Bearer {token}");

 try {
   var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Esto es el código que tengo, he buscado por Internet y es exactamente igual, el token esta correcto, lo he probado con insomnia y funciona perfectamente

Alguien ha pasado algo igual?

Comment: Puede llegar a depender mucho de dónde es la API. Por lo general quién la provee brinda instrucciones de como consumirla. Sería bueno que menciones quién te brinda la API o de qué servicio es.

Comment: yo soy quien brinda el API, es mio, yo lo consumo desde 3 proyectos, uno den tkinter con python, otro con vuejs y otro con ionic y en ninguno he tenido este problema

Comment: incluso te devuelve 401 con la línea que tiene comentada, `//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);` xq esa es la forma que está en la doc oficial de Microsoft